# Easy to use HTML/CSS/JS builder for web design/development with minimal coding

Tags: web-development, ide, html-editor, gui-builder

I am looking for a way to create a web front-end with a quick-and-easy-to-learn/minimal-coding framework/builder that will allow me to fully design the page with change on mouse-over and drag and drop.

I have back-end developers working on the back-end, so I don't need a tool for that.

The software should either be working with or compiling HTML/CSS/JavaScript so that minimal redoing will be required to integrate with the back-end and implement it.

GUI is better though I don't mind a text-based tool, but if it is text based, it has to have a minimal learning curve.

Gratis is better, but paid suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you have a look at the questions in [http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html-editor](tag:html-builder)? What do you want to do (in more concrete terms)? Did you search for "Wysiwyg HTML [Your OS]"?

Comment: (1) I did do a small search on softwarerecs but I did not find anything to my liking. (2) I want to create a site that has drag and drop functionality. (3) There are so many out there, but a lot (or most of them) would not fit my requirements. I figured someone might recommend a suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

For drag and drop capabilities I would recommend visual studio 2015 community it is free. It has drag and drop capabilities and has a very nice ide for coding html. Visual studio is meant more for back end developers but you can use it to do front end development.

Answer (score 0):

Wefblow (http://webflow.com) is a great visual coding tool. It is not drag'n'drop in the sense of Wix, though. You still code html and css and even js (https://interactions.webflow.com), but everything is done in a visual way. For example you can see the div-s hierarchical structure as a visual outline where you nest divs or move them around just the way you would do the same with folders in Windows Explorer. Webflow also supports a visual CMS (https://webflow.com/cms).

At the same time you could still add custom code to pages (but you cannot edit the built-in code).